# Java/wsdl/jar class not found compilation issue

Tags: java, maven, ant, jar, wsdl

I am a newbie to wsdl/java... please excuse me for any obvious errors.

Here is my main program. It basically tries to create an object and the class of the object type is referenced from a jar file (of a wsdl). I downloaded these jar files from else where..I didn't write them.

Now, in eclipse, I ensured that I am referencing the jar file properly. I created a lib folder in the root folder, copied the jars under the lib directory and added them to build path.

However, I still see compilation issues.

```
   import com.myplatform.soap.IdtoAcctWebservice.IdToAccountWebserviceLocator;

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       IdToAccountWebserviceLocator obj = new IdToAccountWebserviceLocator();
       ...
       ...
   }
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?  I tried to unzip the jar file but there are tons of sub-files and I wasn't sure where I could search for the exact class definition.

I would really appreciate if someone could help understand what could be going wrong.

Comment: "compilation issues" is vague.  Edit your question to show us the actual errors.

Comment: Are you sure  compilation fails due to missing class?  Do you see errors at import

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is your JAR file does not contain those class which you are using. Try another jar file.

Answer (score 0):

try to search .class file inside your jar file in the following directory...

/com/myplatform/soap/IdtoAcctWebservice/IdToAccountWebserviceLocator.class

If this is not found then, the jar is incorrect. or may be you are using wrong class.
(Assuming jar is on classpath. - you can try importing some other class which you can see inside jar file to check if it is really on classpath or not.)